# Storing/Saving a database value each x hours/days and displaying it as a chart - Gathering statistics

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, arrays, charts

So, for each member there is a value saved on database "timeOnline" which basically increases as member stays online. What I want is a way to store this database value for each hour/day for a month. After a month the data will basically get overwritten by the new data. Now, obviously creating a new table with 31 columns and saving the data on the corresponding column seems a bit too "rough", I was thinking of saving it as an array on the database using serialize. Now I need to get the data from the old table (for each member) and save it to the new table, and I am supposing that I have to set up some kind of cron job.

Given that I managed to save those data correctly, now i need to get them, and create a chart (basically chart showing the time online per last 30 days). And here I am assuming I have to subtract the old date (which is timestamp) from the new one, and before I do this I have to unserialize the array.

Now, I was guessing this is not the best idea and I have no experience with charts. Id like if someone suggested me a better idea (if there is any, or if this isn't the worst), and a solution about the charts, which should I use.

An example of what I want would be GameTracker

http://www.gametracker.com/player/SpaceCow%28%E2%98%82%29/216.52.148.47:27015/

EDIT: Most likely this way i wont even need a second table, Id just create a new column and insert the array there.

Comment: I doubt I understand your problem correctly (try to more explanation or example?) but the approach you are talking about of saving data is serialized value is defeating the purpose of using relational database.

Comment: The charts on the link i provided explain it the best.

Comment: Sure seems over complicated when all you need is to store dateTime for login and logout then query by date ranges and get diff for each entry

Comment: Well, not necessarily login time. The data is saved from other source, and all i have is timeOnline column which saves seconds the member has been online.

Comment: Basically statistic purposes

Comment: @Klajdi You need to be more specific, you said, "I have timeOnline column which saved seconds the member has been online".
What does that actually mean ?
1) Do you have seconds value associated to each hour for a day and for 30/31 days (acording to the second line of your original post) in that column or, (2) do you have just the seconds value of the whole day for that day.

Comment: Just the seconds a member has been online in total. I want to achieve sth like a statistic chart showing how many hours he has been online in x day.

Comment: @Klajdi No worries, consider it done. Now I think I/or somebody else can help you on here. I am writing and will post within 15mins. Be patient.

Comment: Thanks, i appreciate it, i'd be great with an overall idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am assuming you are familiar with PHP and know how to pass values from PHP and use it on JavaScript

There is this Javascript library I have found for making graphs. This is very easy. Even If you haven't worked with graph/chart before, it is going to get easy as of now.

First include this [Github: Chart.js](https://github.com/chartjs/Chart.js) Javascript library named Chart.js in your HTML code. There may be/are other libraries out there, I chose this one(Charts.js) randomly. You don't need jQuery library at all for Chart.js to be used. Though you can include it as well and use it accordingly.

For exapmple I have included CDN link for the Chart.js library. You can download and include that chart.min.js file from your project folder.

```
<script src=https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.6.0/Chart.min.js></script>
```

Since the type of chart that is in that GameTracker link which you have posted is called "Vertical" Bar Chart (see the yellow vertical bars? that's it).

Now Go to Vertical (Under Bar charts) to see an example in [Chartjs.org Types of chart](http://www.chartjs.org/samples/latest/)
Now you are seeing something useful that is how your graph is going to look like (don't worry about negative values in that example we won't need that since player don't play/go-online for negative hours)

[ [Now the coding part](http://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/) ]
Graph will be rendered inside the Canvas element. Take a look at the following code and then Just read the "comments" I have included in the code, you'll get the idea.

```
<div id="d1">
<canvas id="myChart"></canvas>
</div>

<script>
var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart").getContext('2d');
var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: 'bar',
    data: {
        labels: ["Day1", "Day2"], // this is where you put the day value you can write whatever you want and it will show on the bar. There are two bars in here; first is "Day1" and second is "Day2". You can add as many bars as you want.
        datasets: [{
            label: 'Player Time in Hours for each day', // set the lable for the graph in here, whatever you like.
            data: [12, 9],  // this is where you put the number values in hrs; first value "12" hrs is for "Day1" and so on.
            backgroundColor: [
                'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)', //this is the color of first bar, you can use normal values like "crimson" or "yellow" or etc as well instead of rgba or rgb values.
                'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.2)' //color of the second bar and so on
            ],
            borderColor: [
                'rgba(255,99,132,1)', //border color for the first bar
                'rgba(54, 162, 235, 1)' //border color for the second bar and so on
            ],
            borderWidth: 1
        }]
    },
    options: {
        scales: {
            yAxes: [{


                  ticks: {
                        beginAtZero:true
                    }
                }]
            }
        }
    });
    </script>
```

You can read Documentation for further information, it is all in there.

CSS code for "div" tag: (you can set whatever you like, this is just for an example, when I ran that code myself I found out that putting canvas element inside the div and setting the div width solves the x-y scaling issue which I was getting with the default/original code)

```
    #d1{
          border: 1px solid black;
          Width: 400px;
       }
```

Comment: Do you have any idea how to save the database value every x days/hours? Or should I do it the way i explained above? Using cron jobs.

Comment: @Klajdi you can use date functions, start collecting value(updating column) from 00:00:00 AM till 23:59:59 PM for each day as a different element in that array. 

Lets say you get timeOnline = 774 seconds, save it into sql column at a given moment, also save it into an another variable say lastSeconds js/php, all you now need is keep comparing lastSeconds to timeOnlline, if timeOnline == lastOnline is TRUE then do nothing. If it is FALSE then update your column with this new timeOnline value.

You haven't even shown any code from your side and without that no one can help you further.

Comment: Well, since most of my question was answered Im marking this as answered. Thanks